# Parser Error Debugging VS2008

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I create new VS2008 asp.net application it builds fine.  But when I start debugging I get below error in browser.  I've rebuilt the app.  The Inherits clause of the markup page matches the class in the code-behind C#.  Any clues?

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Parser Error 
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'WebApplication3._Default'.

Source Error: 


Line 1:  <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication3._Default" %>
Line 2:  
Line 3:  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">


Source File: /Default.aspx    Line: 1 


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.4952; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.4927
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the namespace from the `Inherits` attribute:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
```

Comment: Whoa that was it.  How could this be?  That's automatically generated by vs.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually because the code-behind class name / namespace has changed, but the .aspx page hasn't been updated (or visa versa).

You should open up the code behind of your page and make sure that the namespace and class name match whats in your .aspx page (and that the class is marked as public).

```
 namespace WebApplication3
 {
     public class _Default
     {
         // ...
```

Comment: Yes they match as mentioned in the question.  I'm suspecting a corrupt vs install.

Comment: @maatthias Try using [fusion logging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(v=vs.71).aspx) to diagnose the load failure - you might have referenced another assembly that couldn't be loaded.  Also make sure that your project is built and up-to-date.